# Which one of it is a better query and why?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to get the names of the Departments and the number of Employees in it. Test is my schema.

So I come up with two queries that give me the same result -

**First**

```
SELECT Department.Departmentname, 
                            (
                                SELECT COUNT(*)
                                FROM test.Employee
                                WHERE Employee.Departmentid = Department.idDepartment
                            ) AS NumberOfEmployees
FROM test.Department;
```

**Second**

```
SELECT Department.Departmentname AS NAme,COUNT(Employee.idEmployee) AS Employee_COUNT 
FROM test.Department 
LEFT JOIN test.Employee 
ON Employee.Departmentid = Department.idDepartment 
GROUP BY Employee.Departmentid ;
```

Which of the two is the best and efficient way to get the required result? Any other solution is welcome.

Please explain why a particular solution is better

Comment: Have you looked at the plan for the two queries?

Comment: Plan? Are you asking me where am I using these queries?

Comment: You might want to look at the query execution plan (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/execution-plan-information.html).

Comment: The [query plan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) explains how the database is going to handle the two queries. Looking at that will give you your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My *preference* for expressing the logic is the second query, which I would write as:

```
SELECT d.Departmentname AS Name, COUNT(e.idEmployee) AS Employee_COUNT 
FROM test.Department d LEFT JOIN
     test.Employee e
     ON e.Departmentid = d.idDepartment 
GROUP BY d.Departmentname;
```

Note the use of table aliases and the fact that the `GROUP BY` uses the same columns as the `SELECT`.  However, in MySQL, this query will not use an index on `DepartmentName` for the `group by`.  That means that the `GROUP BY` is doing a file sort, a relatively expensive operation.

When you write the query like this:

```
SELECT d.Departmentname, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM test.Employee e
        WHERE e.Departmentid = d.idDepartment
       ) AS NumberOfEmployees
FROM test.Department d;
```

No explicit `group by` is needed.  With an index on `Employee(DepartmentId)` this will use the index for the `count(*)`, so this version would normally perform better in MySQL.

The difference in performance is probably negligible until you start having thousands or ten of thousands of rows.

Comment: Your explanation is in favour of the first query, but your preference is the second one?

Comment: @MayurDeshmukh . . . Yes.  Most SQL engines know how to optimize the first version so it runs as well as or better than the second version.  I consider that MySQL is deficient in this area of optimization, because the second will take advantage of an index not used in the execution plan of the first.